# combining two indicator alerts into one alert when both conditions are met

Tags: pine-script, indicator, alerts

I am busy trying to write up my own script for trading view, using two indicators, both have built-in alerts.

How does one write a code to combine two indicator ALERTS into one?

ie. so that only one alert will signal when both indicators alert conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

Use `and` to create a compound condition on the two separate conditions. Once you have your compound condition, use it to trigger your `alertcondition()`.